# No call to clientaccesspolicy.xml

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 Web application which has Silvelight 4 ,which provides video streaming, in it. It works well in localhost, that is calls clientaccesspolicy.xml file. However after I publish it to my server, it doesn't call the clientaccesspolict.xml file, and not works!

What sould I do?

Comment: Is the ClientAccessPolicy.xml file in the root of the web service on your server? If not it should be.

Comment: what is the url of published silverlight app and what is the url it tries to access? Could be cross zone access...

Comment: Both of them is in the same domain.

Comment: The obvious reason for me is that the access policy file is located in the root of service, not in the root of the parent website. I mean if the service has address localhost/MyApplication/MyService.svc , the file must be located at the path localhost/ClientAccessPolicy.xml without a name of application.

Comment: if both urls share same domain than silverlight will not request clientaccesspolicy file, since there is no cross domain access.

Comment: So what is the problem that it is not requesting streams. It cannot display the streams...

Answer (score 1):

If they are within the same domain then it shouldn't need to access the clientaccesspolicy.xml

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd debug this problem:

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and watch for the request to ClientAccessPolicy.xml. Does it succeed? Does it 404? If it 404s, check the URL and verify your webhost is configured to serve XML files, and verify the file is where it's supposed to be.